# Max value from joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

Operations (op_id,super,name,last)
Orders (or_id,number)

Operations:

```
+--------------------------------+
|op_id| super| name        | last|
+--------------------------------+
|1       1      OperationXX    1 |
|2       1      OperationXY    2 |
|3       1      OperationXC    4 |
|4       1      OperationXZ    3 |
|5       2      OperationXX    1 |
|6       3      OperationXY    2 |
|7       4      OperationXC    1 |
|8       4      OperationXZ    2 |
+--------------------------------+
```

Orders:

```
+--------------+
|or_id | number|
+--------------+
|1        2UY  |
|2        23X  |
|3        xx2  |
|4        121  |
+--------------+
```

I need query to get table:

```
+-------------------------------------+
|or_id |number |max(last)|   name     |
|1      2UY     4          OperationXC|    
|2      23X     1          OperationXX|    
|3      xx2     2          OperationXY|    
|4      121     2          OperationXZ|    
+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you try `MAX()` and `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, a community for **asking** specific **questions** normally to do with, or linked with coding which are answered by volunteers.  When posting a "question", it's really important to ask one; what is yours? When posting, you also need to show what you have tried. Stack Overflow is not a free coding service; the users here are **unpaid** volunteers, using their free time to help you so please make sure you make every effort to solve the problem first and don't post asking for people to do your work for you. Thanks.

Comment: . . .  Take a time & carefully read stack rules & specially `Larnu` comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use corelared subquery and join

```
select o.*,a.last,a.name from
(
select super,name,last from Operations  from operations t
 where last = (select max(last) from operations t2 where t2.super=t.super)

) a join orders o on t1.super =o.or_id
```

you can use row_number as well

```
with cte as

(
select * from 
(
select * , row_number() over(partition by super order by last desc) rn
from operations
) tt where rn=1

) select o.*,cte.last,cte.name from Orders o join cte on o.or_id=cte.super
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT Orders.or_id, Orders.number, Operations.name, Operations.last AS max
    FROM Orders
    INNER JOIN Operations on Operations.super = Orders.or_id
    GROUP BY Orders.or_id, Orders.number, Operations.name;
```

I don't have a way of testing this right now, but I think this is it.

Also, you didn't specify the foreign key, so the join might be wrong.

Comment: You need to use `.` not `-` as your object part separator. `[Table]-[Column]` is wrong, it's `[Table].[Column]`.

Comment: You're right, I haven't used this version of sql in a while. I'll edit it now

Comment: @Sami well, do you mind telling me *why*? It could help the op

Comment: you don't appear to be pulling any aggregates with your query, there's no MAX, other than as a column alias...

Comment: @JonTout thank you. I think I didn't really understand the question, but after looking at the other answers I think I know now what he want to do. I edited it but, like I said, I have no way of testing this right now.